# $A\subseteq B$ if and only if ($A\cap C)\cup B$ = B for every set C.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$A\subseteq B$ if and only if ($A\cap C)\cup B = B$ for every set $C$.

Is this a true or false statement? I think it is true but I am just not sure how to show it for every set $C$?

Answer (score 1):

if $A\subseteq B $ then for every set $C$, we have: $(A\cap C)\subseteq B$ so $(A\cap C)\cup B \subseteq B$. obviously $B\subseteq (A\cap C)\cup B $

conversely; let $C=A.$ Then $B= (A\cap C)\cup B =A\cup B$ so $A\subseteq B$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's true. Let $A\subseteq B$. For every set $C$,

$$(A \cap C) \cup B = (A\cup B) \cap (C \cup B) = B \cap (C\cup B) = B.$$

Conversely, if $(A\cap C) \cup B = B$ for every set $C$, then in particular, $(A\cap A) \cup B = B$, i.e, $A\cup B = B$. Therefore, $A\subseteq B$.

Answer (score 0):

This Statement is true. For arbitrary $C$ you have $A \cap C \subset A \subset B$. Therefore $(A \cap C) \cup B=B$.